# Larger voting buttons on mobile

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, mobile-web

Can I request on a mobile device that the voting buttons are made larger? I frequently find that I accidentally down vote when I meant to upvote and it takes me a couple of presses to remove the down vote before I can upvote. I think larger buttons on mobile devices might significantly improve this experience.

Comment: Is this about the mobile *website*, or the mobile *app*?

Comment: Sorry, this is the mobile site. Didn't even know there was an app. Might go take a look!

Comment: BTW you can upvote without removing the down-vote. The score of the question will jump by 2.

Comment: @anatolyg that I also didn't know. I should spend more time reading on meta!